# How can i get the Video duration of a selected video from input in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

//selectedFileData is array of selected video file from input

```
const data = new FormData();
for (let i = 0; i < selectedFileData.length; i++) {
  data.append("file", selectedFileData[i]);
  data.append("fileSize", convertSize(selectedFileData[i].size, "MB"))
  data.append("videoDuration",(i want to append video duration of video from here));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modern browser's URL API's `URL.createObjectURL()` with an non appended video element to load the content of your file.

```js
const data = new FormData();
for (let i = 0; i < selectedFileData.length; i++) {
  let videoElem = document.createElement('video');
  videoElm.preload = `metadata`;
  
   video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
    let duration = video.duration;

    data.append("videoDuration", duration);
  }

  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);;
  
}
```